# how to handle promises in this code refactoring

Tags: node.js, request-promise

I am refactoring some code that was using a Promise-Mysql library. I am now porting it to Mysql2 library.
So far so good but I need help on a piece of code that is working with promises (I am not yet so good with promises).

The original code:

```
Promise.all([
        db.query("UPDATE gantt_tasks SET text = ?, start_date = ?, duration = ?, progress = ?, parent = ? WHERE id = ?",
            [task.text, task.start_date, task.duration, task.progress, task.parent, sid]),
        updateOrder(sid, target)
    ])
        .then(function (result) {
            sendResponse(res, "updated");
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            sendResponse(res, "error", null, error);
        });
    });
```

has become:

```
con1.execute("UPDATE gantt_tasks SET text = ?, start_date = ?, duration = ?, progress = ?, parent = ? WHERE id = ?",
        [task.text, task.start_date, task.duration, task.progress, task.parent, sid], function (err, result, fields) {
            //if (err) throw err;
            if (err) { sendResponse(res, "error", null, error); }
            updateOrder(sid, target);
            sendResponse(res, "updated");
        });
```

`sendResponse` is the following:

```
function updateOrder(taskId, target) {
    var nextTask = false;
    var targetOrder;

    target = target || "";

    if (target.startsWith("next:")) {
        target = target.substr("next:".length);
        nextTask = true;
    }

    return db.query("SELECT * FROM gantt_tasks WHERE id = ?", [target])
        .then(function (result) {
            if (!result[0])
                return Promise.resolve();

            targetOrder = result[0].sortorder;
            if (nextTask)
                targetOrder++;

            return db.query("UPDATE gantt_tasks SET sortorder = sortorder + 1 WHERE sortorder >= ?",[targetOrder])
                .then(function (result) {return db.query("UPDATE gantt_tasks SET sortorder = ? WHERE id = ?",[targetOrder, taskId]); });
        });
}
```

My question is: how do I change the `return Promise.resolve();`? In my code there is not a promise anymore...

Comment: ...what? Why _did_ you have `return Promise.resolve();`; you're already in a `.then` callback, that's completely pointless, just `return;`. Why don't you just promisify the API so you don't have to refactor everything else?

Comment: the original code is coming from an external developer. And this is actually the only piece of code where they were using promises

Comment: Going from promises to callbacks is imho a step backwards.

Comment: @Evert There are sometimes performance reasons for moving from promises to callbacks. In a lot of big codebases moving to callbacks from promises is actually a step **forward**. The performance gain is not insignificant. I've seen several times that just switching back to callbacks can gain performance almost as much as switching to a completely different language like Go.

Comment: @evert, imho in this situation where I am chaining the execution of three different queries one after the other callbacks are the right thing also in terms of code readability. Yes promises are the new way but here they are not bringing added value (IMHO obviously)

Answer (score 0):

Modernized:

```js
async function updateOrder(taskId, target = "") {

  let nextTask = false;

  if (target.startsWith("next:")) {
    target = target.substr("next:".length);
    nextTask = true;
  }

  const result = await db.query("SELECT * FROM gantt_tasks WHERE id = ?", [target]);
  if (!result[0]) return;

  let targetOrder = result[0].sortorder;
  if (nextTask) {
    targetOrder++;
    await db.query("UPDATE gantt_tasks SET sortorder = sortorder + 1 WHERE sortorder >= ?",[targetOrder]);
    await db.query("UPDATE gantt_tasks SET sortorder = ? WHERE id = ?",[targetOrder, taskId]); });
  }

}
```

`async` functions always return  a promise, so this also fulfills your original requirement.

You should probably use a transaction for this though.